# Loop JSON Insert in SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I am inserting JSON into SQL and it is working successfully.

My only problem is I need to loop it, here is my existing Query:

```
DECLARE @jsonFieldAttributesChoicesData NVARCHAR (MAX) = '*Some JSON String*'

TRUNCATE TABLE FD_FieldAttributes_Choices

INSERT INTO FD_FieldAttributes_Choices
SELECT      parent_choice_id = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.parent_choice_id'),
            id = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.id'),
            label = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.label'),
            label_for_customers = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.label_for_customers'),
            value = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.value'),
            stop_sla_timer = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.stop_sla_timer'),
            [default] = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.default'),
            position = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.position'),
            deleted = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.deleted')
    FROM OPENJSON(@jsonFieldAttributesChoicesData, '$[13].choices') AS j
```

As you can see from the bottom line, I am inserting object 13 of my choices into the table (working fine):

```
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonFieldAttributesChoicesData, '$[13].choices') AS j
```

What I need to do though, is run through a loop, starting at 0, and working up until it has run through the whole JSON string. As it stands there are 14 choices objects, but in the future, there could be potentially more (or less), so as soon as it hits the last one, it then stops.

```
'$[0].choices'
'$[1].choices'
'$[2].choices'
...
'$[13].choices'
'$[14].choices'
and so on...
```

How would I do this? As I have said, my insert works fine, its just the loop I am struggling with.
Of course, this JSON string is initiated by a Webpage, so including JavaScript is an option. Ie. Stripping out all the choices, and concat into a single string. But I don't know how to do that either.

Any help would be spot on!

Thank you :)

Comment: All those calls to `JSON_VALUE` seem excessive. Why not use a `WITH` clause in your call to `OPENJSON`? Sample JSOn and expected results would really help us help you here.

Comment: try something like: select * from openjson(@jsonFieldAttributesChoicesData) x cross apply openjson(x.value, '$.choices') with (parent_choice_id int, id int) ... well you get the drift

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).